# Newly created OneNote notes don't sync to Onedrive

Tags: sync, 7.8, onedrive, onenote

Having a really frustrating time with OneNote.

Every time I add a OneNote note on my phone (WP7.8) via the big PLUS icon it says it lives in `PERSONAL - UNFILED NOTES`. What that location signifies is kind of unclear. I want to sync/see these notes in my Onedrive on other computers - it doesn't show up there.

I guess this new note just live on the phone. Weirdly it doesn't show up if I tap **Phone** in the Locations screen:
[image]

That just says "No documents".

I *can* track it down if I tap the Notebooks icon:

[image]

It's in there under Personal - Unfiled Notes.

But there's no way that shows up in Onedrive.

I think I just want my newly created notes to be created by default as Onedrive notes, not hidden away in the phone. Furthermore, there's seems no way to move/copy an existing Phone based note to Onedrive.

It's really really useless for me to find I've created a note on the phone which I can't access from other devices.

How to solve this?

Comment: Sorry but as far as I know it is created on SkyDrive. But don't give up. Share the OneNote by email with you and open the file with notepad. Probably it will have the address on it.

Answer (score 4):

OneNote should create the default Personal notebook on Onedrive. It creates the notebook in the Documents folder on Onedrive. Can you see that folder via the browser?

Unfortunately the OneNote app on Windows Phone doesn't allow you to move sections or notebooks around like you can on the Desktop client/Windows 8 app.

If you don't have Windows 8 or a desktop client you can use the OneNote web app in Onedrive to do most of the more advanced tasks, but you still can't move a section between notebooks.

The first thing to try would be to create a new notebook in Onedrive under your Documents folder using a browser [Onedrive](http://onedrive.live.com). After creating the notebook try looking in the Onedrive location on your phone. After you open it once it remember it in your notebooks section.

Hope that helps.